# Insert Value in css line

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add the `padding-top` value to the css that I append in the header , but only `color` is working:

```
        var PaddingTOp = $('#PaddingTOp').val();
        var PaddingRight = $('#PaddingRight').val();
        var PaddingBottom = $('#PaddingBottom').val();
        var PaddingLeft = $('#PaddingLeft').val();

        //Class Name
        $("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ color:#f00; padding-top: PaddingTOp ;} </style>").appendTo("head");
        $(".container").addClass("redbold");
```

Comment: You are just setting the string `PaddingTOp` as the value and not the contents of that variable. Use concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ color:#f00; padding-top: "+PaddingTOp+" ;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

Comment: nice work , now i need all the  other var if they  have value will added to the line also .. i`m trying but the vars added without any values .!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var PaddingTOp = $('#PaddingTOp').val();
    var PaddingRight = $('#PaddingRight').val();
    var PaddingBottom = $('#PaddingBottom').val();
    var PaddingLeft = $('#PaddingLeft').val();

    //Class Name

    var cssToApply = "color:#f00;";
    $.trim(PaddingTOp).length > 0 ?  cssToApply + "padding-top:"+PaddingTOp +";" : "";
    $.trim(PaddingRight ).length > 0 ?  cssToApply + "padding-right:"+PaddingRight +";" : "";
    $.trim(PaddingBottom ).length > 0 ?  cssToApply + "padding-bottom:"+PaddingBottom +";" : "";
    $.trim(PaddingLeft ).length > 0 ?  cssToApply + "padding-left:"+PaddingLeft +";" : "";

    $("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ "+ cssToApply +"} </style>").appendTo("head");
    $(".container").addClass("redbold");
```